# How to call `gform_is_delayed_pre_process_feed` after payment in payment gateway gravity form plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I developed a payment gateway plugin for gravity form. I want to update post when addon update post is active.

now I redirect customers to gateway and when they return to my callback function, I call  gform_is_delayed_pre_process_feed` like this:

```
public static function Verify()
{

  add_filter("gform_is_delayed_pre_process_feed", true);

  //code
}
```

but add_filter doesn't work.

‌I call add_filter after payment in call function But add_filter didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the correct form is:

```
add_filter("gform_is_delayed_pre_process_feed", '__return_true');
```

The second parameter for the add_filter function must be callable and wordpress define a helper function called `function __return_true()`.